# Problems with regex and lists comprehension with multiple functions and f-string

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension

i have a probleme, two in fact. Firstable, i work on an NLP projet. I need to write a script to tag words, replace non standard POS (parts of speech) by universel POS and extract name entities with their tag. And i need to put the result in file like this. There are two files. The first one only prints the words with their POS and NER tag (named entity recognition). For the first file, i have this kind of output:

```
Consuela    NOUN    B-PERSON
Washington  NOUN    B-ORGANIZATION
.   .   O
a   DET O
longtime    ADJ O
House   NOUN    B-ORGANIZATION
staffer NOUN    O
and CONJ    O
an  DET O
expert  NOUN    O
in  ADP O
securities  NOUN    O
laws    NOUN    O
.   .   O
is  VERB    O
a   DET O
leading VERB    O
candidate   NOUN    O
to  PRT O
be  VERB    O
chairwoman  NOUN    O
of  ADP O
the DET O
Securities  NOUN    B-ORGANIZATION
and CONJ    O
Exchange    NOUN    B-ORGANIZATION
Commission  NOUN    I-ORGANIZATION
```

It's exactly what i want but now i have to convert the NER tag to universal NER tag and created a dict with key/value (non standard/standard). Here the POS has been converted in universal format (NOUN, DET, ADP etc...) But now, when i want to apply the same method with the my second file to convert NER tag, i obtains that :

```
Consuela    NOUN    BIBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORGPERSON
Washington  NOUN    BIBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORGORGANIZATION
.   .   BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
a   DET BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
longtime    ADJ BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
House   NOUN    BIBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORGORGANIZATION
staffer NOUN    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
and CONJ    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
an  DET BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
expert  NOUN    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
in  ADP BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
securities  NOUN    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
laws    NOUN    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
.   .   BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
is  VERB    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
a   DET BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
leading VERB    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
candidate   NOUN    BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
to  PRT BIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGBIBIB-LOCLOCPERSPERSORGORG
```

It's for sure no what i want. It's when i want to change my dictionnary (correspondence table between NER) between the first one

```
dict_ner = {'ORG':['I-ORGANIZATION', 'B-ORGANIZATION', 'FACILITY'], 'PERS':['I-PERSON', 'B-PERSON'], 'LOC':['I-LOCATION', 'B-LOCATION'],
'MISC':['DATE', 'TIME', 'MONEY', 'PERCENT'],'LOC':['I-GPE', 'B-GPE']}
```

and the second one because i want to print the I or B before (I-PERS, B-PERS etc...) It's important for my project. I use this dict and the result is awful.
My regexp module build  the entire regex to replace non standard tag in a dict where the regex is the key and the the value is the value by which to change the old one(s).

```
dict_ner = {'I-ORG':'I-ORGANIZATION', 'B-ORG':'B-ORGANIZATION', 'ORG':'FACILITY', 'I-PERS':'I-PERSON', 'B-PERS':'B-PERSON', 'I-LOC':'I-LOCATION', 'B-LOC':'B-LOCATION',
'MISC':['DATE', 'TIME', 'MONEY', 'PERCENT'],'LOC':['I-GPE', 'B-GPE']}
```

Here is my code. Don't pay attention to french commentaries

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!usr/bin/env python3

from contextlib import ExitStack
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags
import re

# dictionnaire : table de correspondance des étiquètes NER (conll to standard)
dict_ner = {'I-ORG':'I-ORGANIZATION', 'B-ORG':'B-ORGANIZATION', 'ORG':'FACILITY', 'I-PERS':'I-PERSON', 'B-PERS':'B-PERSON', 'I-LOC':'I-LOCATION', 'B-LOC':'B-LOCATION',
'MISC':['DATE', 'TIME', 'MONEY', 'PERCENT'],'LOC':['I-GPE', 'B-GPE']}

# loading correspondance table between Penn Treebank POS and standard POS from file
def load_pos_table():

    try:
         
        with open('POSTags_PTB_Universal_Linux.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as universal:

            # on commence par charger notre dictionnaire avec la table des étiquettes POS Penn Treebank, POS NLTK
            dict_pos = {}
            for sent in universal.readlines():
                for line in sent.splitlines():
                    cut = line.strip().split()
                    dict_pos[cut[1]] = dict_pos.get(cut[1], list()) + [cut[0]]

        return dict_pos

    except Exception as erreur:
        print(f'load_pos_table : {erreur}')

def convert_format(line, dic):

    try:
        rx_dctvals = {re.compile("|".join(sorted([to_regex(v) for v in val], key=len, reverse=True))):key for key, val in dic.items()}

        #Version 3.8+
        return [line := rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line) for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items()][-1]
        """
        version 3.7-
        for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items():
            line = rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line)
        return line
        """

    except Exception as erreur:
        print(f'convert_tag: {erreur}')

def to_regex(x):

    r = []
    if x[0].isalnum():
        r.append(r'(?<![^\W])')
    else:
        if any(l.isalnum() for l in x):
            r.append(r'\B')

    r.append(re.escape(x))
    
    if x[-1].isalnum():
        r.append(r'\b')
    else:
        if any(l.isalnum() for l in x):
            r.append(r'\B')
    return "".join(r)

def extract_entities(doc):
    return list(map(lambda sent: tree2conlltags(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))),
 sent_tokenize(doc)))

def main():

    try:

        with ExitStack() as stack:
            
            file = stack.enter_context(open('formal-tst.NE.key.04oct95_sample.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
            # fichier d'extraction des entités nommées avec étiquettes non standards 
            result_file_ner = stack.enter_context(open('wsj_0010_sample.txt.ne.nltk', 'w', encoding='utf-8'))
            # fichier avec étiquettes standards NER
            result_file_ner_standard = stack.enter_context(open('wsj_0010_sample.txt.ne.standard', 'w', encoding='utf-8'))

            pos_table = load_pos_table()
            content = file.read()

            [[result_file_ner.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) for name, tag, ner in line] for line in extract_entities(content)]
            [[result_file_ner_standard.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', {**pos_table, **dict_ner})) for name, tag, ner in line] for line in extract_entities(content)]

    except Exception as error:
        print(f'main error : {error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Furthermore, i'm not about these two list comprenhension

```
            [[result_file_ner.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) for name, tag, ner in line] for line in extract_entities(content)]
            [[result_file_ner_standard.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', {**pos_table, **dict_ner})) for name, tag, ner in line] for line in extract_entities(content)]
```

extract_entities(content) returns a list of tuples of 3 elements (word, POS, NER or not (0))
I'm not sure if my problem concerns my regex module. I don't know.
If you could help me, i would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When the value was a string my list comprehension iterated trough it char by char ans thus i had one regex by char. I couldn't find anything interesting.  I've modified this line

```
rx_dctvals = {re.compile("|".join(sorted([to_regex(v) if not isinstance(val, str) else to_regex(''.join([t for t in val])) for v in val], key=len, reverse=True))):key for key, val in dic.items()}
```

What a stupid error. I lost a day for this.